# Subsonic not working behind nginx due to ;jsessionid= being add to every single URL

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I started using nginx as a front-end in order to standardize my services access via sub-domains. It works well for pydio and webmail (RainLoop, very good), but Subsonic doesn’t log in.

There is no error message, it just returns to log in page instead of showing my music library.

See attached that even the colours and format of the front page is different (right version) compared to direct access (left version).

Nginx is appending the ";jsessionid=" piece to every single address and that seems to be hurting Subsonic behavior.

What am I doing wrong? I browse the forum and people with more complex setup (SSL, for example) where able to put nginx proxy for Subsonic up and running.

My setup is:

Subsonic server

- HP microserver at home
- Ubuntu 13.10 x64
- Subsonic 4.9.beta2 (build 3634)
- Apache Tomcat/6.0.37, java 1.7.0_25

Nginx server

- Digital Ocean cheap server (512MB, 20GB SSD)
- Ubuntu 13.10 x64
- nginx version: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pydio.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:9090/pydio/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subsonic.mydomain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:8070/subsonic/;
    }

}

Comment: Any update on this?